# ng serve --open is not opening welcome page

Tags: angular

I Installed nodejs and angular using below commands and opening the application. New web browser is opening but welcome page is not displaying in the browser window only empty page is showing.

Used below command

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@latest

ng new my-app

cd my-app

ng serve --open
```

http://localhost:4200/index.html

opening browser with above url but showing blank page.
Please let me know how to resolve this issue and show Angular welcome page.

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you try to access `http://localhost:4200/` directly?

Comment: Also look at browser console, may be some error shown there.

Comment: http://localhost:4200/index.html is not your route page like other server side framework. Also look console you can identify error as said by @RomanLitvinov

Comment: I tried http://localhost:4200/  it is also giving me blank page